# Search for links in webpage, follow them, and return pages with no links in R

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, web-crawler

I am writing an update to my [rNOMADS package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rNOMADS/index.html) to include all the models on the NOMADS web site.  To do this, I must search the html directory tree for each model.  I do not know how deep this tree is, or how many branches it contains, beforehand.  Therefore I am writing a simple web crawler to recursively search the top page for links, follow each link, and return the URLs of pages that have no more links.  Such a page is the download page for model data.  [Here is an example](http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_cmcens.pl) of a URL that must be searched.

I want to get the addresses of all web pages below this one.
I have attempted this code:

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_cmcens.pl"

WebCrawler <- function(url) {
    doc <- htmlParse(url)
    links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")
    free(doc)
    if(is.null(links)) { #If there are no links, this is the page we want, return it!
        return(url)
    } else {
       for(link in links) { #Call recursively on each link found
           print(link)
           return(WebCrawler(link))
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have not figured out a good way to return a list of all the "dead end" pages.
Instead, this code will only return one model page, not the whole list of them.
I could declare a global variable and have the URLS saved to that variable, but I am wondering if there is a better way to go about this.  How should I go about constructing this function to give me a list of *every single page*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is in the recursion:

```
## THIS IS INCORRECT
for(link in links) { #Call recursively on each link found
           print(link)
           return(WebCrawler(link))   <~~~ Specifically this line
        }
```

There is no recursive property here, you are just digging in deep along a single branch.

```
      *
    /   \
    \
     \
      \ 
       \
        *
```

You don't want to **return** the value of `WebCrawler(link)`.
Rather you want to **capture** that value, then return the collection of values.

```
ret <- vector("list", length=length(links))
for(link in links) { #Call recursively on each link found
           print(link)
           ret[[link]] <-  WebCrawler(link)   <~~~ Specifically this line
        }
return(ret) # or  return(unlist(ret))
```

#### Update:

It might be worth considering what you expect as a final output?  You will get a deeply nested-list.  If you just want the end nodes, you can `unlist(.. recursive=TRUE, use.names=FALSE)` or you can even unlist as you go along, but that will probably slow you down more.  Might be worth benchmarking it to be sure.